# Add/Remove class on a certain viewport (Or any way to improve animation quality on mobile)

Tags: jquery, animation, viewport, removeclass

I've made scrolling animations with `viewportChecker.js` and `animate.css`. The problem is the animations are really sluggish on mobile devices. The elements which animates have a class "scroll".

So, there are actually 2 questions. One is how do I improve the animation quality on mobile devices? Or how do I remove the class `scroll` from every element on a certain viewport?

I've tried a couple of things that I found on the internet. I've tried `$(window).resize();` and a lot of other things people mentioned. But, I couldn't apply any of them, I am still an amateur when it comes to jquery.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is your answer. You can do a check to see the size of the viewport. The code would look something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    if ($(window).width() <= "size at which scroll class should be removed"){
        $("element with scroll class").removeClass("scroll");
    }
});
```

If you also want this to run every time the window is resized you could surround the if statement with:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    //Code from above here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of different factors which might affect why your scroll animations are sluggish. Have a look at how large the page is (are there lots of images?). What device are you using to test it?

You can remove the CSS class of an element with the `.removeClass(<name>)` function in jQuery. For example, to select remove the scroll class from every element which has it, you can use:

`$('.scroll').removeClass('scroll');`

You can specify element / attribute selectors much like you'd specify them in CSS as well, so to remove the .scroll class from any `<p>` element you could use:

`$('p.scroll').removeClass('scroll');`

Or to remove .scroll from any element nested within another element which has the .noscroll class:

`$('.noscroll .scroll').removeClass('scroll');`